# Comparing three matrices for similarity? What test is logical?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, biostatistics

I have 3 matrices. For these matrices, the first variable (column index) is cell line, second variable (row index) is gene, and the third variable (cell value) is expression. These 3 matrices were sampled by different people, and I want to see how comparable they are in terms of results. What I imagine is finding the coefficient of variation to see how much each point varies, or looking for Pearson correlation. I was wondering if this is logical, and if not what is a better method?

Comment: by 3 matrices were sampled by different people, you mean that each matrix was generated by one different person?

Comment: @develarist The 3 matrices are each gene expression data produced by a different institute, but they were conducted for the exact same cell lines and genes.

Comment: Yes that's what i mean

Comment: @develarist Just wanted to clarify to be safe

Comment: Sounds like multivariate paired Hotelling's t-square: http://www.real-statistics.com/multivariate-statistics/hotellings-t-square-statistic/paired-sample-hotellings-t-square/

Comment: @Elenchus The website makes it seem like it can't concurrently compare 3 different models, in this case matrices.

Comment: @ebehr I imagine you could do pairwise comparisons, similar to https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/pairwise-t-test/

Comment: @ebehr Perhaps MANOVA would be the way to go here. You would have to flatten your matrices into 1D arrays and then feed them into MANOVA.